# Apache hive exception noClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/iterable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

When issuing a command like count or unique in the command line
I am getting an exception and booted from the console
Not sure where to check the entire log but here is the excerpt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.spark.SetSparkReducerParallelism.process(SetSparkReducerParallelism.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.SparkCompiler.runJoinOptimizations(SparkCompiler.java:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.SparkCompiler.optimizeOperatorPlan(SparkCompiler.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TaskCompiler.compile(TaskCompiler.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10857)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Iterable
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 4):

this issue usually because of classpath config problem，try this may useful

step 1: find this code in $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive(perhaps backup this file is better):

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${HIVE_LIB}/*.jar

for f in ${HIVE_LIB}/*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
done
```

step 2: add spark lib ,like hive_lib

```
for f in ${SPARK_HOME}/jars/*.jar; do
     CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
done
```

after this,the  hive executeable file seems like this

```
for f in ${HIVE_LIB}/*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
done


for f in ${SPARK_HOME}/jars/*.jar; do
     CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
done
```

SPARK_HOME which point your spark install location, as i used spark 2.0.0,spark libs is under ${SPARK_HOME}/jars,i found some answers by google but these does not really solve my question,so i modify the hive executeable shell scripts and add spark lib, works for me,wish to help you

Comment: I added those two scripts at the end of hive file, but hive table creation ok, but if i run select * from tablename getting same error.